# Installing a SSL certificate on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am new on AWS.

I have already created an EC2 Ubuntu Instance with Apache2.

On the other hand I have a domain and a SSL certificate for that domain.

I have also created a Routed 53 hosted zone. I can now access the EC2 Instance with any browser just entering my domain name.

Now I need to install and setup the SSL certificate on the EC2 Instance.

I have been searching for hours for a good tutorial or documentation that shows me what steps to follow to install the SSL certificate.

Please, I would appreciate any help, a link to a working tutorial or documentation for my needs.

Comment: What is your tech stack?   Each stack has slightly different ways of handling SSL.

Comment: @stdunbar, I am using the terminal to connect to the EC2 instance, I am used to write linux commands. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Somewhere you've got a web server.  Which one?  Do you also have a proxy (for example, Apache Tomcat with Nginx in the front)?

Comment: @stdunbar, I have an Apache2 web server installed on the AWS Ubuntu instance, but wiithout Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EC2 is none other than blank machine.

For apache2 setting up SSL certificate you have to following step mention in link

https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache/

Make sure your ssl configuration should be inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`.

In this file all ssl certificate mappping and vhost entry for domain have to create to use https protocol using 443 port.

Make sure you have enable 443 port in your EC2 security group in AWS.

```
<VirtualHost [IP ADDRESS]:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@ssl-tutorials.com
DocumentRoot var/www/html/example/
ServerName www.example.com
ErrorLog www/home/logs/error_log
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl-tutorials_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl-tutorials.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl-tutorials_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```